# ORMLite improve the select performance

Tags: sql, orm, h2, ormlite

I use ORMlite with H2 database on Java server. I have a dataset of 450k rows. And I have the following distribution:

- From 0 to 300k: every 300-th row has the status 1
- From 300k to 420k: every 50-th row has the status 1
- From 420k to 450k: every 4-th has the status 1

Other rows has the status 2. So, overall about 10900 rows has the status 1, others has the status 2.
**Please note** that the distribution is approximate, so the SQL query cannot rely on the numbers above.

Then I need to select the last 8k rows, which does not have the status 2. I have tried the following:

1. First order the rows by time creating and then query 8k rows with limit function:

   ```
       SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `Status` <> 2 LIMIT 0,100000
       queryBuilder.orderBy('time_saved', false);
       queryBuilder.limit(8000L);
   ```

The problem with this solution, that it takes quite long to retrieve all elements: about 6 seconds. The most of time takes this order function: about 2 seconds for all processing and about 4 seconds for ordering.

2. Query all elements, but then trim the resulting array. The performance of this solution is quite good for me.

So I was wondering, whether there is another solutions, which can be better for solving such problem. I know that I can set the offset for QueryBuilder to improve the performance, but I don't know the starting number for this offset.

Thank you in advance.

p.s. Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with ORMLite so any supporting links will be appreciated. Thank you.